# Sending transactions without downloading the blockchain

Tags: transactions, blockchain, private-key, external-api, resend

I'm rather new to this world and it's a bit overwhelming.

I would like to manage an eth address from a lightweight device (think of a raspberry). I want to handle incoming transactions i.e resend some of the received eth to another address. Here are my issues:

1. Can I do this handling without having to sync all the ethereum blockchain?
2. If so, what language/framework do you advise?
3. I want to handle an existing wallet and I got the private key, how could I use it? I mean, just pass the private key in a function or I have to restore it somehow? (I guess this depends on point 2)

Any pointing to the right direction will be greatly appreciated :)

Thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I do this handling without having to sync all the ethereum
>   blockchain?

Yes, you can use some framework.

> If so, what language/framework do you advise?

JavaScript/[Etherscan API](https://etherscan.io/apis).

> I want to handle an existing wallet and I got the private key, how could I use it? I mean, just pass the private key in a function or I have to restore it somehow? (I guess this depends on point 2)

You need to have your keystore file to reside in keystore folder near your chaindata. When you will try to sign a transaction with your address, you will first need to unlock account with your password, which you used on keystore file generation.

**or**

You can [`sendRawTransaction`](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethsendrawtransaction) only with your private key.